# Magento 2 - Save data of customer from a form in database

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, knockoutjs, forms

I wish I could create a form with several inputs dedicated to the customer's attributes in my first custom checkout step.
This form will have to save the data in the database, in the customer information. Is there a module that allows you to do this?